# VBA MS Word - If string contains number larger than 9999

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to check a string to see if there are any references of a number that is more than or less than 4 characters long.

So here are some examples of numbers that may be within the string:

- 0123
- 3443
- 9320

So it is not as easy as selecting the number and checking if it is more than 999 and less than or equal to 9999 as numbers can start with a 0.

Here is an example of the data which may be stored in a string

- Profile ID: 3243, 9432, 0232, 3423
- Profile ID: 3243/3454/0213/3253
- Test 2434 2342 4325 2132

Here are some examples of what would return valid and invalid

```
0324    TRUE
39234   FALSE
2393    TRUE
192     FALSE
```

As there is no fixed dilemma for separating the data I am not sure how I would go about separating the numbers from the string.

My original idea was to only extract numbers and replace all others with a space. Then use the space as a dilema. If the string was blank then skip that for the check but if it contained a value then check if the length of the string was 4 characters.

All solutions or ideas are welcome

---

Comment: Split the string with spaces Split(string," "), loop all splits and check if is a number, if it is a number check if it is more than 999. You can use Regex or Replace to remove the special characters :/, and even text.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function CheckNumbers(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    s = " " & s & " "
    CheckNumbers = Not s Like "*#####*" _
                   And Not s Like "*[!0-9]###[!0-9]*" _
                   And Not s Like "*[!0-9]##[!0-9]*" _
                   And Not s Like "*[!0-9]#[!0-9]*"
End Function
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string is selected, you could use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim StrData As String, StrTmp As String, i As Long
With Selection
  If InStr(.Text, vbCr) Then
    .Collapse wdCollapseStart
    .MoveEndUntil vbCr, wdForward
  End If
  StrTmp = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Split(.Text, vbLf)(0), vbTab, " "), "/", " "), ",", " "), "  ", " ")
  For i = 1 To UBound(Split(StrTmp, " "))
    StrData = Split(StrTmp, " ")(i)
    If IsNumeric(StrData) Then
      If Len(Split(StrTmp, " ")(i)) <> 4 Then
        .InsertAfter " Invalid": Exit For
      End If
    End If
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

As coded, the macro inserts ' Invalid' after the string if it contains an out-of-range number.